# BuiltinClassLoader cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

Using Eclipse 2020-03 version.
After adding "ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar" as class path for one of project which has dependency with ORACLe encountered below error during build.

BuiltinClassLoader cannot be resolved to a type.

This class has been used in one of project for loading jar files from specific folder and in specific formats

Answer (score 2):

There are some rather strange things about your Question.

The class `jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader` is an internal class that was added in Java 9.

However, according to the [Oracle 12.1.0.2 JDBC driver download](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-upc-downloads.html) page:

- The JAR file names are `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojdbc7.jar` not `ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar`.
- The `ojdbc7.jar` (the later one) is certified for Java 7 and Java 8.  That means it *should not* have any dependencies on classes added in Java 9.

So ... I have a couple theories:

1. You have an JDBC JAR file of dubious origin.  Depending on where you got it, it possibly contains malware of some kind.  I recommend downloading the drivers from the Oracle site; see above.
2. You have a genuine Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc7.jar) but someone has renamed it.  If this is the case, the unresolvable class name error *cannot be* caused by the driver JAR file.  It might actually be in your code or in some other library that you are using:

   - Try searching your source code.
   - Try unpacking the JARs that you are building against and using `javap ... | grep BuiltinClassLoader` on the `.class` files to see if you can spot the class / JAR that is responsible.

   Neither your code or 3rd-party code should depend on the `BuiltinClassLoader` class defined in `jdk.internal.loader`.  It is an internal class.
3. The unresolvable `BuiltinClassLoader` class has a different package name.  Search your code and the JARs as above.